# Print everything right of ":" at the same width

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a small script that is supposed to format some string so that they more read-able. The input is a list with strings inside of the list. The input might look like this (note: this is the same as input as in the image, except that the image better contrasts the input and output):

```
['last name: Callum', 'first name: Brian', 'middle name: Mosbey', 'balance: $0']
```

Each string has a `:` in it. I want all of the text right of the `:` to be printed on the same width, so that it is easier to read the information. The output I want is this (note: I got this working with METHOD 2, but not with METHOD 1):

```
['last name:   Callum', 'first name:  Brian', 'middle name: Mosbey', 'balance:     $0']
```

Here is my approach on solving the problem:

1. First we iterate over the list of string and store in another list at what index the `:` can be found
2. first we find out which string has the `highest_index` of  `:`
3. We iterate over the list of strings again(new iteration), we calculate the `difference` for the current index of `:` to that of the `highest_index`
4. (still in the iteration) to the right of where we found the `:` we insert `' '` * `difference`

### Problem: I have 2 implementations of this solution. METHOD 1 is shorter, but does not work. METHOD 2 is longer but works at lest. Why does METHOD 1 not work?

[image]

---

CODE:

```
def even_spacing(lst):
    new_lst = []  # list for the final output
    index_colon = []  # list of the indexs where ':' is found, for each line

    # find where the ':' in each line
    for line_string in lst:
        index_colon.append(line_string.find(':'))
    highest_index = max(index_colon)  # the highest index ':' can be found at in any of the lines

    # we add the extra spaces
    for index, s in enumerate(lst):
        difference = highest_index - index_colon[index]  # how many spaces will be needed


        # METHOD 1 not working, less code
        # new_lst.append(''.join(list(s).insert(index_colon[index]+1, ' '*difference)))  # insert at the index we found the proper number of spaces

        # METHOD 2, working, but more code
        list_letters = list(s)
        list_letters.insert(index_colon[index]+1, ' '*difference)
        new_lst.append(''.join(list_letters))

    return new_lst

test = ['last name: Callum', 'first name: Brian', 'middle name: Mosbey', 'balance: $0']
print even_spacing(test)
```

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4XENXE7v)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `insert` method of lists acts in place (mutates the list, and does not return it) and returns `None`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a.insert(1, "inserted")
>>> print a
[1, 'inserted', 2, 3]
>>> print b
None
```

So you can't chain operations involving `.insert`, which is why

```
''.join(list(s).insert(index_colon[index]+1, ' '*difference))
```

won't work.  This is basically `''.join(None)`.

Your second method works because you're calling `insert` but not trying to process what it returns.

Comment: so is my second method the right way to do it than?

Comment: To perform that specific operation, yes.  I might have approached the underlying problem a little differently -- probably used `split(":", 1)` and then found the maximum length that way, rather than using lists -- but your method should work too.

Answer (score 2):

instead of solving your bugs (that @DSM did well), know you can make vertical alignment pretty easily in python by either using:

- tabs:

which is the easiest way, but may not scale to very long left hand side strings

```
>>> test = ['last name: Callum', 'first name: Brian', 'middle name: Mosbey', 'balance: $0']
>>> for s in test:
>>>     print s.replace(': ', ':\t').expandtabs(8)
last name:      Callum
first name:     Brian
middle name:    Mosbey
balance:        $0
```

N.B.: you can change the value of expandtabs depending whether the alignment is ok or not.

- string formats:

which is a bit more complicated, but scale very well with the long left hand side strings

```
>>> test = ['last name: Callum', 'first name: Brian', 'middle name: Mosbey', 'balance: $0']
>>> longest = reduce(lambda x, y: max(x, len(y.split(': ')[0])+2), test, 0)
for s in test: 
    l, r = s.split(': ')
    print "{:<{longest}} {}".format(l+':',r,longest=longest)
```

see [string formats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) documentation for more about this.

I also think that @phil-cooper's solution for calculating `longest` is smarter than mine:

```
longest = max(s.index(':') for s in test)
```

and you should use his solution (but still add `2` as `:` never gets counted in his or my solution).

Finally, you look like you don't know about [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
strings = ["{:<{longest}} {}".format(l+':',r,longest=longest) for l,r in [s.split(': ') for s in test]]
```

so, I hope this is helping, even though I'm not *directly* answering your question by giving you other options ;-)

Comment: in your first code window the output is not what I want. its not aligned properly

Comment: as I say, it's a good trick when you want to align in a hurry, but it's not working 100%, but you can cheat, let me add a few space on the right and... nothing, I can make the words aligned in the editor, in the shell, but not on the html output.

Comment: I actually just found out a way to make example 1 work correctly! just by using expandtabs() with a custom value.

Answer (score 1):

You need only three elements

The max len:

```
all_strs = ['last name: Callum', 'first name: Brian', 'middle name: Mosbey', 'balance: $0']

maxlen = max(s.index(':') for s in all_strs)
```

a proper format string:

```
fmt = "%%-%is:%%s" % maxlen  # this resolves to '%-11s:%s' in your case
```

your final result:

```
[fmt % tuple(s.split(':',1)) for s in all_strs]
```

**Edit:**
to format using format:

```
fmt = "{{:{}}}:{{}}".format(maxlen)  # resolves to '{:11}:{}'

[fmt.format(*s.split(':',1)) for s in all_strs]
```

Explanation:  (OP requested) the approach is to dynamically create the format string.  This requires odd looking doubling up on chars like `%{}`. thus the odd looking `"{{:{}}}:{{}}"` which is just an effort to end up with a "normal" format string. Similar issue with the "%%" in the first example

After that, it's just a matter of splitting each string into two and reassembeling with the constructed format sting.

Hope that helps.

In python, unlike c and other languages, [strings are immutable objects](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-python-strings-immutable.htm), not a list of chars.  That is the essence of why your first method couldn't work.

Comment: I disagree with your last sentence.  `insert` is acting on a *list*, not a string, and if `insert` returned a copy of the modified list it would have worked just fine.

Comment: I find the last two pieces of code quite confusing. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: N.B.: `%` based formatting is now deprecated (with the current switch towards python3)

Comment: @DSM you are 100% correct, I should have looked at OP code more closely and you answered his question about METHOD 1 exactly